# Using vectorized logical not in pandas to filter a frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame I would like to prune. I want to take out the rows where the section is 2 and the identifier does not start with a digit. First I would like to count them. If I run this

```python
len(analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2].index)
```

I get the result 1247669

When I narrow things down and run this

```python
len(analytic_events[(analytic_events['section']==2) & ~(analytic_events['identifier'][0].isdigit())].index)
```

I get exactly the same answer: 1247669

I know, for example, that ten of the rows have this as their identifier

> .help.your_tools.subtopic2

which does not start with a digit, and that 15,000 rows have this as their identifier

> 240.1007

which **does** start with a digit.

Why is my filter passing all the rows rather than just those whose identifier does not start with a digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` for working with text functions and `str[0]` for first value of string, last `sum` for count `True`s values:

```
mask= ((analytic_events['section']==2) & 
       ~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit()))

print (mask.sum())
```

If performance is important and no missing values use list comprehension:

```
arr = ~np.array([x[0].isdigit() for x in analytic_events['identifier']])
mask = ((analytic_events['section']==2) & arr)
```

EDIT:

> Why is my filter passing all the rows rather than just those whose identifier does not start with a digit?

If test output of your solution:

```
analytic_events = pd.DataFrame(
                        {'section':[2,2,2,3,2],
                         'identifier':['4hj','8hj','gh','th','h6h']})

print (analytic_events)
   section identifier
0        2        4hj
1        2        8hj
2        2         gh
3        3         th
4        2        h6h
```

Get first value of column:

```
print ((analytic_events['identifier'][0]))
4hj
```

Check if digit of scalar:

```
print ((analytic_events['identifier'][0].isdigit()))
False

print (~(analytic_events['identifier'][0].isdigit()))
-1
```

With chain with first mask it is converted to `True`:

```
print ((analytic_events['section']==2) & ~(analytic_events['identifier'][0].isdigit()))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: section, dtype: bool
```

So it working same like second mask not exist:

```
print (analytic_events['section']==2)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: section, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, the analysis of what my naive 'solution' was doing is especially helpful

Comment: Why does isdigit() give -1 on the last line of your test output of my solution when applied to False and not throw an error?

Comment: @dumbledad - If check `print (~False)` it return `-1`, but if convert ti to bool get `True` - `print (bool(~False))`

Comment: I am getting a type error from your first solution, when I run it I get `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`

Comment: @dumbledad - it means there are missing values like `analytic_events = pd.DataFrame(
                        {'section':[2,2,2,3,2],
                         'identifier':['4hj','8hj','gh','th', np.nan]})`

Comment: @dumbledad - And solution is convert missing values to `False` like `mask= ((analytic_events['section']==2) & 
       ~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit().fillna(False)))`

Comment: @jezrael, I've added a follow-on question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54442997/575530) as I cannot find any missing data.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `str` attribute on the `identifier` series like this:

```
sum((analytic_events[(analytic_events['section']==2)) & ~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit())].index)
```