# "TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'" not down to NA (not available)?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to filter a pandas data frame. Following @jezrael's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54439631/575530) I can use the following to count up the rows I will be removing:

```python
mask= ((analytic_events['section']==2) & 
       ~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit()))
print (mask.sum())
```

However when I run this on my data I get the following error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) 
>    in 
>         1 mask= ((analytic_events['section']==2) &
>   ----> 2        ~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit()))
>         3
>         4 print (mask.sum())
>
> c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **invert**(self)
>      1454     def **invert**(self):    1455         try:
>   -> 1456             arr = operator.inv(com.values_from_object(self))
>      1457             return self.**array_wrap**(arr)
>      1458             except Exception:
>
> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

The accepted wisdom for that error, `bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`, is that the unary operator encountered a NA value (for example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297788/575530))

The problem is that I do not have any such missing data. Here's my analysis. Running

```python
analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]['identifier'].str[0].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

gives the results:

> 2    1207791
>   3      39289
>   1        533
>   .         56

Or running

```python
analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit().value_counts(dropna=False)
```

gives the results

> True     1247613
>   False         56

(Note that the amounts above sum to the total number of rows, i.e. there are none missing.)

Using the more direct method suggested in @jezrael's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54443038/575530)

```python
analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]['identifier'].isnull().sum()
analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]['identifier'].str[0].isnull().sum()
```

both produce the output zero. So there are no NA (not available) values.

Why am I getting the error

> TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

from the code at the start of this post?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, but sadly it is confidential, even though it wouldn't mean anything to you :(

Comment: In my case the only non-digit start to an identifier is `.`, so I can replace `~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit())` with `(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0]=='.')`. But it would be great to know why the more general code throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need filter by first condition and then again in filtered values:

```
m1 = analytic_events['section']==2

mask = ~analytic_events.loc[m1, 'identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit()

print (mask.sum())
```

Comment: I get an identical `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'` from that.

Comment: I see it is tested a bit different code, but if try `print((analytic_events['identifier'].astype(str).str[0].str.isdigit()).value_counts(ropna=False))` instead `analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit().value_counts(dropna=False)` what it return?

Comment: I get the same results from that.

Comment: @dumbledad - What return `print (np.unique(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit().values))` ?

Comment: `np.unique(analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit().values)` gives the result `array([False,  True])`

Comment: @dumbledad -  And `print (np.unique(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit().values))` ? Why you are give there `analytic_events[analytic_events['section']==2]` ? It is not necessary. But if same output then no idea, maybe some pandas bug :(

Comment: It is necessary, without that there are null values: `array([nan, False, nan, ..., nan, True, nan]`. As you can see in the question I'm restricting this to the rows where the section is 2 (it's the first bit of the mask)

Comment: @dumbledad - So it is problem - because my solution working with all data, not only filtered. So `~(analytic_events['identifier'].str[0].str.isdigit()))` testing in all column data.